# What is Speech Downloader?

Tags: macos, mac, popups

I had a window popping up, notifying me that "Speech Downloader" is trying to modify my system settings.

Can anybody help me out, what kind of process or app "Speech Downloader" is?

Comment: I'm getting the same pop-up. Watching this thread too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7696701.

Comment: This is Apple training you to click OK to accept random unidentifiable pop ups on your system.... i.e. "Don't Think".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its a program in your Mac for Siri updating the Voice to text function

See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution here.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7696701?start=0&tstart=0

Need to go to System Prefs > Accessibility > Speech > System Voice (drop down) > Customize.   Then uncheck any voices in the list that have a "Upgrade to enhanced quality" check box next to them.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the voice of Siri. If you change it to, for example, Male (America), that message will pop up. If it's the first time that pops up, it's probably because you enabled Siri for the first time.